# missing S3 method but higher level-function works

Tags: r, methods, r-grid, gtable

I'm trying to pin down a problem with `grobWidth` applied to `gtable` objects (see `gtable:::widthDetails.gtable`); an issue arises when the size is specified as a sum of units (`unit.arithmetic` object),

```
library(grid)
u = unit(1,"npc") + unit(2,"mm")
grid:::absolute.units(u)
#Error in UseMethod("absolute.units") : 
# no applicable method for 'absolute.units' applied to an object of class #"c('unit.arithmetic', 'unit')"
```

Remarkably, `absolute.size` works, even though it calls `grid:::absolute.units`,

```
grid::absolute.size(u)
#[1] 1null+2mm
```

How is that possible?

Comment: Don't you need to establish a plotting frame before using npc units?

Comment: no, but amusingly this brings about another problem, `grid::absolute.size( unit(1,"in") + unit(2,"mm"))` yielding `1null+2mm`. And I thought Imperial units were confusing.

Answer (score 3):

OK, browsing the [grid source code](https://github.com/wch/r-source/blob/trunk/src/library/grid/R/unit.R#L819), I found out that the method *is* defined,

```
grid:::absolute.units.unit.arithmetic(u)
```

but it's not exported. So `absolute.size()` knows about it, because it's in the package namespace, but calling it from outside (e.g. gtable) fails.

Comment: I thought you wrote grid :}

Comment: easy mistake with my kiwi accent